# Inproper texture mapping while using QGLBuffer

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, shader, qt4.7

I wrought basic OpenGL 2.1\ES example for supposed target platform, using Qt 4.7.1 library on Windows. Target is some kind of Linux, with Qt 4.8 max available, no glm or similar libraries. Embedded GPU supports ES 1.0 or OpenGL 2.1 only. Example is "classic" texture cube, which you might met in various OpenGL examples.. but those examples use direct calls to OpenGL functions, what isn't available to me for lack of proper headers and glew - both on development and on target platforms. Development platform is Windows 7.

Geometry

```
 static const int vertexDataCount = 6 * 4 * 4;

 static const float vertexData[vertexDataCount] = {
 // Left face
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//0
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,//1
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,//2
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//3

// Top face
-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, //4
-0.5f, 0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, //5
 0.5f, 0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, //6
 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, //7

// Right face
0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//8
0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,//9
0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,//10
0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//11

// Bottom face
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//12
 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,//13
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,//14
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//15

// Front face
 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,//16/
 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,//17
-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,//18
-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,//19

// Back face
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//20
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//21
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,//22
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f //23
};

// Normal vectors
static const int normalDataCount = 6 * 4 * 3;

static const float normalData[normalDataCount] = {
// Left face
-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

// Top face
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

// Right face
1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

// Bottom face
0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,

// Front face
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

// Back face
0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f
};


// Texure coords
static const int textureCoordDataCount = 6 * 4 * 2;
static const float textureCoordData[textureCoordDataCount] = {
1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,

1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,

1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,

1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,

1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,

1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f
};


// Indices
//
// 3 indices per triangle
// 2 triangles per face
// 6 faces
static const int indexDataCount = 6 * 3 * 2;

static const unsigned int indexData[indexDataCount] = {
0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,  // Left face
4,  5,  6,  4,  6,  7,  // Top face
8,  9,  10, 8,  10, 11, // Right face
12, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, // Bottom face
16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // Front face
20, 22, 23, 20, 21, 22  // Back face
};
```

This is how I  load texture

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

m_texture = bindTexture(QImage("cube.png"));

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

if(m_shaderProgram)
    m_shaderProgram->setUniformValue("texture", 0); // texture unit 0, assuming that we used
```

Vertex shader

```
#version 120

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texturecoord;

varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
varying vec2 outtexture;

void main( void )
{
    // Transform the normal vector
    fragmentNormal = ( modelViewMatrix * vec4( normal, 0.0 ) ).xyz;

    // Calculate the clip-space coordinates
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vertex;
    outtexture = texturecoord;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 120

// in
uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec2 outtexture;
varying vec3 fragmentNormal;
// out
// gl_FragColor

void main( void )
{
    // Calculate intensity as max of 0 and dot product of the
    // fragmentNormal and the eye position (0,0,1).
    float intensity;

    intensity = max( dot( fragmentNormal, vec3( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) ), 0.15 );
    gl_FragColor = intensity * texture2D(texture,outtexture); // vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

I bind buffers this way (prepareBufferObject is little snippet function I took from Qt sample):

```
// Prepare the vertex, normal and index buffers
m_vertexBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer );
if ( !prepareBufferObject( m_vertexBuffer, QGLBuffer::StaticDraw, vertexData, sizeof(vertexData) ) )
    return;

m_normalBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer );
if ( !prepareBufferObject( m_normalBuffer, QGLBuffer::StaticDraw, normalData, sizeof(normalData) ) )
    return;

m_texBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::IndexBuffer );
if ( !prepareBufferObject( m_texBuffer, QGLBuffer::StaticDraw, textureCoordData, sizeof(textureCoordData) ) )
    return;

m_indexBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::IndexBuffer );
if ( !prepareBufferObject( m_indexBuffer, QGLBuffer::StaticDraw, indexData, sizeof(indexData) ) )
    return;


loadShaders("vertexshader120.glsl", "fragshader120.glsl");

// Enable the "vertex" attribute to bind it to our vertex buffer
m_vertexBuffer->bind();
m_shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer( "vertex", GL_FLOAT, 0, 4 ); //xyzw
m_shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray( "vertex" );

// Enable the "normal" attribute to bind it to our texture coords buffer
m_normalBuffer->bind();
m_shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer( "normal", GL_FLOAT, 0, 3 ); //xyz
m_shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray( "normal" );

m_texBuffer->bind();
m_shaderProgram->setAttributeBuffer( "texturecoord", GL_FLOAT, 0, 2 ); //uv
m_shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray( "texturecoord" );

// Bind the index buffer ready for drawing
m_indexBuffer->bind();
```

Finally , paintGL method

```
void GWidget::paintGL()
{
    QMatrix4x4 model;
    model.setToIdentity();
    model.rotate(m_rotation);

    QMatrix4x4 mv = m_view * model;

    // MVP = projection * view * model
    // uploading MVP into shader (may add code to check if MVP was update since last redraw)
    m_shaderProgram->setUniformValue("modelViewMatrix",mv);
    m_shaderProgram->setUniformValue("projectionMatrix",m_projection);

    // set up to render the scene
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw stuff
    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES,       // Type of primitive to draw
                indexDataCount,     // The number of indices in our index buffer we wish to draw
                GL_UNSIGNED_INT,    // The element type of the index buffer
                0 );                // Offset from the start of our index buffer of where to begin
}
```

Everything works except texture looks misaligned and skewed -both on development and on target platforms. I checked UVs and that they correspond to proper vertices - yet it looks like order of texture coordinates is wrong. Where is error here?

For reference: [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8d39yjmnv6zkrj/sample1.zip)

This is my first attempt at  usage of flexible pipeline, so I could do something dumb there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up your texture coordinate buffer as an index buffer:

```
m_texBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::IndexBuffer );
```

Since it contains vertex attribute data, it should be created as:

```
m_texBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
```

Comment: *headdesks repeatedly* Thank you, that worked. Ironically, _meant_ it be vertex originally.. That's very same case when author can't see own typo - I 'd not guessed that changing buffer type would just skew texture - I'd expected black cube or something equally dysfunctional.